# How to load a particular view when device's orientation is landscape any where in the app and switch to the lat view when portrait?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uideviceorientation

Hey in my app i have to load a particular view whenever the device is in landscape mode no matter in which view the user is. And also have to switch it back to the last view where the user was when device turned to portrait.

Any suggestions? or link to any tutorial??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try something like write your own UIViewController subclass, wich only implements the appeareance of your custom view on change of interfacorientation. Something like this:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
     DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
    //navigation controller ruft den bdv Controller auf
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
    [dvc release];

}
```

All your other classes now inherit from this custom UIViewController.
Of course this would only be a solution if you have ViewControllers for all your views.

Hope it helps